# Timeline and Forecast On Hand Quantity

Tags: excel, time, vba

I need to project available product based on on hand quantity - commitments - number of days till receipt of Purchase Order * avg use plus open Purchase Order Qty. I can get this for each line as shown below in EXCEL (SKU = same product):

[image]

Any ideas on how to make line 1's Projected Available the starting On Hand qty for line 2 and have Days to ETA count from last receipt date? There are multiple SKUs in this table (query result) and I need to filter.  I know there is no code here, just trying to work through it. I think Id have to show results in a different sheet. Thanks

Comment: To get the projected available correct, I **suspect** all that you need to do is add, to the current projected available, the sum of all PO Qtys that have an ETA earlier than the current one, so (assuming your image shows columns A:I) add `+SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,A2,F:F,"<"&F2)` to the end of the formula in I2.  (I think that then makes the formula `=C2-D2+B2-H2/30*E2+SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,A2,F:F,"<"&F2)`)

Comment: Is it feasible to sort your data by `SKU`and then by `ETA`? If so, there are fairly obvious solutions. Other, possibly irrelevant, points:` Avg Use` appears to be approx 30 times average daily rate of use; `DAYS TO ETA` is perhaps 1 day short (depends whether period is inclusive of both start and end dates);`Commited` possibly needs to be subtracted only once and, if so, would best be subtracted only from the initial `On Hand` amount not from any future values obtained as projections.

Comment: Thanks for the responses ... DMM, that is the logic I was trying to work through. The sort will actually be done upon the division (####) the SKU belongs to. I failed to mention that   I think I need to flesh your answer out, use subtotal to create the dashboard and maybe some VBA to manipulate the table.  Good catch on the '30 days', that is a forced monthly avg based on daily totals (22.8 maybe more realistic for days worked).